# Referencing a value of this HTML snippet

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently in the process of writing a bot to auto-purchase items from the store at [supremenewyork.com](http://supremenewyork.com) based on user-provided keywords. The bot is a Chrome extension so I am using JavaScript. So far the only way I have found to search items is to have the bot open each item's page individually and search its name, but based on internet speed, the bot must wait until the page has loaded fully before doing this, which makes it almost slower than a normal human being. One idea I had was to have the user start the bot on a page like

http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/jackets

where there are titles for each of the items. The html for the names looks like this:

```
<a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/vfp4j6xs9/pcklt5f4g">Supreme®/LACOSTE Harrington Jacket</a>
```

If I find all of these items using

```
var Items = [];
Items = document.getElementsByClassName('name-link');
```

Then I can reference the link in a for loop with with `Items[i].href`. So I can get the link, but how can I reference the part that says "Supreme®/LACOSTE Harrington Jacket?"

Comment: [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Items[i].textContent` instead.

Comment: I think OP wants the text, not the HTML. So to avoid `&nbsp;`, `&amp;` and that sort of thing ending up in the result, it would be better to suggest `.textContent`.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. Glad this had such a simple solution.